# When I perform an update - rows keep updating if I run the query again

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am updating a table as follows:

```
UPDATE dw.distance_test ead
SET distance = tp.distance
FROM dw.distance_tp tp
WHERE ead.ref = tp.ref
AND  COALESCE(ead.distance,0) <> COALESCE(tp.distance,0)
```

Which gives the result 'Query returned successfully: 6 rows affected, 26 msec execution time.'

If I run the same query again it still says gives the result 'Query returned successfully: 6 rows affected, 26 msec execution time.' - I would have thought it would say 0 rows affected as I've already updated the table. Could someone possibly explain what's happening and what can be done to rectify it?

Thanks

Not sure if more info is required, please let me know

Comment: Same transaction?

Comment: Is ref column unique in both tables?

Comment: Yes same transaction

Comment: @Serg The ref in dw.distance_test contains NULLs, the ref in distance_tp doesn't have NULLs. They arent unique, both columns can contain duplicate references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source contains `ref` doubles, for example

```
     distance_tp 
  ref distance
  1   100
  1   200
```

the condition `COALESCE(ead.distance,0) <> COALESCE(tp.distance,0)` is always true for one of the source rows watherver the target values is. So the target is always updated.

Comment: Ah thank you! - Would there be a way around this? Would it be to select distinct on the references in the source table?

Comment: You need  a criteria to select one of the matching rows. Min, max, whatever is suitable for the app logic. So you can use grouping or row_number() to get the only value for the ref=1 for example.

Comment: there are duplicate rows having checked, but, if you kept updating, wouldnt it eventually update the rows that were duplicates? If i run the query n number of times it will still say that 6 rows have been affected

Comment: It there are duplicate rows in the source table as in the answer,  the query will update the target rows at every run.